# C# Calculate LRC (Longitudinal Redundancy Check)

Tags: c#, algorithm, serial-port

I've been researching this everywhere and all the LRC implementation seems to not giving me the right answer. After spending few days on it, I decided to put my code here to see if anyone else can spot the problem.

Here's the code (C#)

```
        //Input Data = "31303030315E315E31303030325E315E31303030375E39395E31303032325E36353631335E"
        //LRC Answer = "30"
        private static string LRC(string Data)
        {
            int checksum = 0;
            foreach (char c in GetStringFromHex(Data))
            {
                checksum ^= Convert.ToByte(c);
            }


            string hex = checksum.ToString("X2");

            Console.WriteLine("Calculated LRC = " + hex);

            return hex;
        }





    //Supporting Function used in LRC function
    private static string GetStringFromHex(string s)
    {
        string result = "";
        string s2 = s.Replace(" ", "");
        for (int i = 0; i < s2.Length; i += 2)
        {
            result += Convert.ToChar(int.Parse(s2.Substring(i, 2), System.Globalization.NumberStyles.HexNumber));
        }
        return result;
    }
```

The current output shows "Calculated LRC = 33". However, the right answer is "30". Can anyone spot what's wrong with this?

Any help will be fantastic!

Comment: It would be good to spell out "LRC"... I presume it's meant to be some sort of check code, like a CRC, or convolutional error correction code (for example Reed-Solomon)?  Your implementation looks like simple parity.

Comment: Ah...   True, thanks for the reminder, it's Longitudinal Redundancy Check.

Comment: The wikipedia article suggests that it's traditional to return the two's complement (`-` in C#) of the sum (not XOR) of the bytes.  But says some protocols use XOR.

Comment: I've implemented based on Wikipedia's pseudo code as well. It's also giving me wrong answer.

Comment: Do you have any documentation for the device you're communicating with?  And it doesn't define the checksum better?

Comment: I know the answer is 30 in hex for sure. I've done this identical task 2-3 years ago with same documentations. The only difference is that this one is done in C# and previous one is done in C++ and I don't have access to the C++ source code that i've created in the past anymore...

Comment: BTW dehexed Data is printable ASCII -- '10001^1^10002^1^10007^99^10022^65613^'

Comment: The weird thing is that if you treat that data like C source code and do the XORs between those numbers (treating each number as decimal) you get `0x1001C`.  Actually, if the last number is decimal and the rest are hex, they'd all be in the same range.

Comment: The Hex was generated via ASCII. Basically that's Name Value Pair, where it's OpCode^Value. Once it is converted into HEX then it'll be sent through RS232 connection to the device. This is so strange that I cannot get 30 for some reason....

Comment: Sorry, I don't see any combination of the encoded bytes or pre-encoding opcodes or anything at all that gives 0x30

Comment: Basically, the goal from the implementation documentation said they are expecting a LRC at the end. The sample answer they give is 30 after calculating LRC against the HEX number....  Unless they need to include STX and ETX, but i remember typically you don't include those two to calculate LRC.

Comment: Well... ETX is then exactly the difference between what you got and what you want.  Is there only this one example?

Comment: that's true, but i don't think we should include ETX if we exclude STX though...   Yes, that's the only one example (I know how annoying when there's not enough examples)....

Comment: Found an interesting link, is it true that we need to include ETX as part of the LRC calculation? ref: http://codeverge.com/embarcadero.delphi.winsock/pos-terminal-lrc-checksum-creation/1075353

Comment: What type of device is this? Link to documentation? I've run through a few variations of LRC on your input and the only way to get 30 is as Ben says.

Comment: I guess now the question is down to standard LRC, do we include ETX and exclude STX during the LRC calculation? Any ideas where I can find some reputable standard guideline and practices?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After several testing, it is confirmed LRC should include ETX and exclude STX during the LRC calculation.